# Use JavaFX look and feel in Swing app

Tags: java, swing, javafx, look-and-feel

I have a large Java Swing application.  Rewriting it is out of the question.  I really like the JavaFX look, and want to use it with Swing components.  Is this at all possible?

Comment: I'm sure you could make your own look and feel to be very close to whatever style you enjoy from JavaFX. The easiest thing might be to look for other look and feels that you like even better and use those as they are ready to go.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove There don't seem to be many up-to-date LaFs out there anymore.  Most are either abandoned or look like they belong in Windows 95.

Comment: Didn't know that. What do you mean by broken, like won't work at all? From what I know Swing hasn't been updated since like 1.6, so no new components would mean to me that the look and feels should still work, but I don't know that much about look and feels to know any better though. I do know that Nimbus works okay still.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove I edited my comment to clarify what I meant.  There must have been a delay before the edit went live.